# Is there an easy way to uninherit javadoc in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to refactor some classes in Java where the original author made an inappropriate base class that I wish to remove. As a first step, I want to divorce the implementation classes from the base class. In the implementation class, it uses the following syntax:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public myMethod()
```

Is there a way in Eclipse that I can quickly bring in the javadoc from the base class without having to copy paste from each method of the base class to the implementation class? Or am I stuck with a tedious copy and paste job? (there are lots of methods...)

Comment: What about having an interface instead of the base class ? It would ,ake little sense to duplicate this doc on all subclasses

Comment: How about using a merge tool.

Comment: I guess it helps if I explain why the base class is inappropriate. The class is a blackbox test. Several different classes extend this abstract class, but there's no reason for this. If the tests really were similar enough, parameterized tests would be more appropriate. But that isn't the case here. Worst yet, the base class has mutable static members to it. Thus if the tests are run together, then they will interfere with each other.

Comment: Are the base class methods abstract or empty?

Comment: @howlger, Yes. They are abstract.

Comment: @Jason Thompson, so you want to push down the Javadoc from an abstract method of the base class to all its implementation classes. To avoid duplicated Javadoc I recommend to use an interface instead.

Comment: @howlger But there isn't a contract. These are tests that coincidentally happened to be the same. As such, they are artificially bound together by some ill conceived abstract class. :)

Comment: @Jason Thompson, But when the abstract class is _ill conceived_ then why keeping the Javadoc? Unfortunately, only if methods are not abstract then the _Push Down..._ refactoring moves/copies the Javadoc to the subclasses.